# My method call changes the universal variable value just once and then that value remains the same but it shouldnt (javaScript)

Tags: javascript, class, methods

```js
class Human {
  constructor(
    kind, name, agility, mana, weapon, health) {
      this.kind = kind;
      this.name = name;
      this.agility = agility;
      this.mana = mana;
      this.weapon = weapon;
      this.health = health;
  }
  attack(enemyHealth) {
    var neprijateljhp = document.querySelector(".enemyhealth");
    if (this.kind === "archer") {
      damageh = 30;
      numberofattacksh = 2;
    } else if (this.kind === "witch") {
      damageh = 30;
      numberofattacksh = 0.5;
    } else if (this.kind === "swordswomen") {
      damageh = 80;
      numberofattacksh = 1.2;
    }
    enemyHealth = enemyHealth - damageh * numberofattacksh;
    neprijateljhp.innerHTML = "Health:" + enemyHealth;
  }
}

var enemyHealth = 200;
let archer = new Human(
    "archer", 
    "Anabelle", 
    "60", 
    "20", 
    "bow and arrow", 
    "200"
);
archer.attack(enemyHealth);
```

Comment: Please provide more details: 1. HTML, 2. What do you expect to happen when you invoke this JS? 3. What happens instead?

Comment: Also the `enemyHealth = ` assignment only modifies the *local* `enemyHealth` variable (defined by the parameter) in the method, not the global one. Notice variables are not passed by reference in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you have several mistake. you dont defined **damageh** and **numberofattacksh** in constructor. then your class cant find them and give you an error.
I defined that and i gave them 0 as default. of course you can change thahs.

this is your Code:

```
class Human {
  constructor(
    kind, name, agility, mana, weapon, health) {
      this.kind = kind;
      this.name = name;
      this.agility = agility;
      this.mana = mana;
      this.weapon = weapon;
      this.health = health;
      this.damageh = 0;
      this.numberofattacksh=0
  }
  attack(enemyHealth) {
    var neprijateljhp = document.querySelector(".enemyhealth");
    if (this.kind === "archer") {
      this.damageh = 30;
      this.numberofattacksh = 2;
    } else if (this.kind === "witch") {
      this.damageh = 30;
      this.numberofattacksh = 0.5;
    } else if (this.kind === "swordswomen") {
      this.damageh = 80;
      this.numberofattacksh = 1.2;
    }
    enemyHealth = enemyHealth - this.damageh * this.numberofattacksh;
    neprijateljhp.innerHTML = "Health:" + enemyHealth;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your contribution. i fixed that and i also realized that the problem may be that the parametar name is the same as the variable name that i use as an argument (enemyHealth). Thank you once agan and good luck with your work!

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve the problem. thanks my friend. you too. <3